# asp.net mvc and apx in one project with owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, owin

I need to add an aspx page into my mvc project, but I always get 404. I founded that in web.config there is owin http handler registration

```
 <add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" />
```

If I commented this my aspx page works fine.
So where can be problem?

Here is my Startup's code:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            Dictionary<string, string> mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
                          {
                              {".apk", "application/vnd.android.package-archive"}
                          };
            StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions
                          {
                              ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(mapping)
                          };
            app.UseStaticFiles(options);
LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new Log4NetLogProvider());

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
            {
                Namespace = "blabla",
                ContainerName = "blabla"
            };
            builder.EntitySet<Common.DataAccess.Sharepoint.Users>("Users");
            var departmentSet = builder.EntitySet<Common.DataAccess.Sharepoint.Departments>("Department");
            builder.EntitySet<Common.DataAccess.Sharepoint.Roles>("Roles");

            var dependentFunction = departmentSet.EntityType.Collection.Function("GetChilds");
            dependentFunction.Parameter<int>("parent");
            dependentFunction.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Common.DataAccess.Sharepoint.Departments>("Department");

            var allUsers = departmentSet.EntityType.Collection.Function("GetAllDependenUsers");
            allUsers.Parameter<int>("department");
            allUsers.Parameter<string>("query");
            allUsers.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Common.DataAccess.Sharepoint.Users>("Users");

            config.MapODataServiceRoute("orgstructure", "orgstructure", builder.GetEdmModel());

            app.UseWebApi(config); 

            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "idsrv3test")
                password.AppendChar(c);

            IdentityServerOptions identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "123123",
                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory
                {
                    UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(typeof (IdentityUserService)),
                    ScopeStore = new Registration<IScopeStore>(typeof (IdentityScopeStore)),
                    ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(typeof (IdentityClientStore))
                },
                RequireSsl = false,
                CspOptions = new CspOptions
                {
                    Enabled = false
                },
                SigningCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Assets.idsrv3test, password),
                CorsPolicy = CorsPolicy.AllowAll,
                AuthenticationOptions = {EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true}
            };

            identityServerOptions.Factory.Register(new Registration<IUserRoleService, UserRolesService>());
            identityServerOptions.Factory.Register(new Registration<IUserDepartmentsService, UserDepartmentsService>());
            app.Map("/open_id", idsrvApp =>
            {
                identityServerOptions.Factory.ConfigureDefaultViewService(new DefaultViewServiceOptions
                {
                    CacheViews = true,
                    ViewLoader = new Registration<IViewLoader, IdentityViewLoader>()
                });
                idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions);
            });

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {AuthenticationType = "Cookies"});

            string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"];
            string clientName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientName"];

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append(Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
            stringBuilder.Append(" ");
            stringBuilder.Append(Common.Constants.Scopes.Portal);

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = baseUrl + "open_id",
                ClientId = clientName,
                Scope = stringBuilder.ToString(),
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                RedirectUri = baseUrl,
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                        // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                        var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(id.AuthenticationType, ClaimTypes.GivenName, ClaimTypes.Role);

                        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = id.Claims
                            .Where(x => x.Type != Common.Constants.Claims.Role && x.Type != Common.Constants.Claims.PortalRole);

                        nid.AddClaims(claims);
                        nid.AddClaims(id.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == Common.Constants.Claims.Role)
                            .Select(x => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x.Value, x.ValueType, x.Issuer, x.OriginalIssuer))
                            );
                        nid.AddClaims(id.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == Common.Constants.Claims.PortalRole)
                            .Select(x => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x.Value, x.ValueType, x.Issuer, x.OriginalIssuer))
                            );

                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(nid, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                        return Task.FromResult(new object());
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
                        {
                            var baseAddress = new Uri(n.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress);
                            if (baseAddress.Host != n.Request.Uri.Host)
                            {
                                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseAddress) {Host = n.Request.Uri.Host};
                                n.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
                            }

                            var redirectBaseAddress = new Uri(n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
                            if (redirectBaseAddress.Host != n.Request.Uri.Host)
                            {
                                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(redirectBaseAddress) { Host = n.Request.Uri.Host };
                                n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
                            }
                        }

                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(new object());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you will use **OwinHttpHandler** you will not be able to serve **aspx** pages. This happens because instead of letting aspx request to reach webforms handler, you impose it to be processed by **OwinHttpHandler** that doesn't know how to handle aspx. So the solution, as you empirically saw, is to eliminate handler adding from web.config.

Comment: I can't eliminate OwinHttpHandler from project. Could you tell me what handler can I add above OwinHttpHandler to handle my aspx page?

Comment: You can look in your IIS in the Handler Mappings section what handler is used for *.aspx and choose the one used for the integrated pipeline (not isapi versions). Try to include this handler in web.config after owin handler with path="*.aspx".